# Is Duration#toDays and Duration#toDaysPart redundant?

Tags: java, java-8, java-9, java-time, duration

In Java 8, the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class offered  the [`toDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toDays()) method, returning a total number of days as a count of 24-hour chunks of time unrelated to calendar days.

In Java 9, the `Duration` class gained handy `to…Part` methods: [`toDaysPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toDaysPart()), `toHoursPart`, `toMinutesPart`, `toSecondsPart`, `toMillisPart`, `toNanosPart`. I understand the need for the hours, minutes, etc. But I wonder about `toDaysPart`.

My question is:

➥ Will [`Duration#toDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toDays()) and [`Duration#toDaysPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#toDaysPart()) ever return different values for a particular `Duration` object?

Comment: I believe that `toSeconds()` and `getSeconds()` are the same too. And (sidestepping) IMHO that system of methods is generally ill-named. `getXxxPart` would have been better, or even just `getXxx()` so it had been consistent with `Period.getMonths()` and `.getDays()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java 11, these lines of source code in [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) are ***exactly the same***.

[Duration#toDays](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Duration.java#L1157):

```
public long toDays() {
    return seconds / SECONDS_PER_DAY;
}
```

[Duration#toDaysPart](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Duration.java#L1265)

```
public long toDaysPart(){
    return seconds / SECONDS_PER_DAY;
}
```

[As of Java 16](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html), no indication is made as to which is deprecated or which is not.  So...keep your eyes peeled for it, is the best advice I could give you here.

Comment: I doubt deprecation is needed. I assume the `toDaysPart` was added on purpose, merely for consistency with the other `to…Part` methods. Thanks for finding the source code, and for writing the Answer.

Comment: But they aren't quite consistent.  All the `to*Part` methods return an `int` whereas the methods, sans `Part`,  return a long - except for the days methods which returns a long in both cases.  This was based on the source as of JDK 14 in the src.zip file from Oracle.

Comment: @WJS Returning `int` versus `long` makes sense in context. The hours part will never be over 23, the minutes part will never be over 59, and so on. But the number of days could be very large, exceeding the limit of a `int`. Ex: `Duration.ofDays( Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L ).toDaysPart()` = `2147483648`.

Comment: @BasilBourque Beware of the minutes with more than 60 seconds: ['Leap Second' Tonight Will Cause 61-Second Minute](https://www.space.com/29795-leap-second-tonight-atomic-clocks.html)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Leap Second is not an issue. The point of a leap second is to harmonize between days (earth rotating on its axis) and years (earth orbiting the sun). Days are not exactly 24 hours long, and vary with the earth's rotation speed varying. A leap second adds a second in order to make the date on the calendar fit our solar time. We want to *pretend* that our dates are exactly 24-hours long. The leap second is a fudge-factor to maintain that pretense. So regarding this Answer, a day in *java.time* chronology is always the same number of seconds long, deliberately ignoring leap seconds.

Answer (score 2):

These methods don't just do the same thing; they are *specified* as doing the same thing in the documentation (linked in your question):

> `public long toDays()`
>
> Gets the number of days in this duration.
> This returns the total number of days in the duration by dividing the number of seconds by 86400. This is based on the standard definition of a day as 24 hours.
> This instance is immutable and unaffected by this method call.
>
> Returns:
> the number of days in the duration, may be negative

> `public long toDaysPart()`
>
> Extracts the number of days in the duration.
> This returns the total number of days in the duration by dividing the number of seconds by 86400. This is based on the standard definition of a day as 24 hours.
> This instance is immutable and unaffected by this method call.
>
> Returns:
> the number of days in the duration, may be negative

The only difference is the word "gets" vs. "extracts" in the descriptive summary. These words don't have different meanings in this context, and the rest is word-for-word identical, in particular the parts specifying what the methods return are identical. In fact, the (OpenJDK) documentation for `toDaysPart` was [recently changed](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/223759fb8af4a28f8ff8563e438ca285a87a9f2d) to clarify that these methods do the same thing. So yes, they are redundant.

According to [the relevant issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142936) on the issue tracker, all of the `to...Part` methods were added together and there wasn't any comment on the fact that `toDaysPart` would be redundant; so we can only speculate about the rationale for adding the redundant method.

Comment: No need to speculate - the same PR conversation makes the rationale clear. The methods are conceptually different - the former represents the duration floored to a whole number of days; the latter represents the days "component" of the duration. Due to preconditions built into Duration they just happen to have the same value and implementation. Duplicate - yes. Redundant - in implementation. The same - no.

Comment: @Dave The PR conversation explains the rationale for adding a bunch of `to...Part` methods, but doesn't explain the rationale for including `toDaysPart` among them when this method could only ever do the same thing as the existing `toDays` method. If there was a rationale for including the redundant method, I would expect to see some acknowledgement in the PR conversation that the proposed `toDaysPart` method is redundant but should be included because [rationale]. Without that, the addition of the redundant method could have been an oversight for all we know.

Comment: It is abundantly clear if you happen to be implementing String conversion utilities across the family of interfaces from java.time. It was no oversight. It is less obvious when looking at Duration in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `get(TemporalUnit)` inherited from `TemporalAmount`, (and `getSeconds()` and the curiously named `getNano()`), are to support the extraction of the temporal components of a composed value.
`Duration` actually only supports `SECONDS` and `NANOS` component access because a `Duration` is the composition of just a `long` seconds component with an `int` nanoseconds component, which together provide nanosecond resolution *and* representation of directed values of up to 2^63 seconds in magnitude (both positive and negative).
The `get_` accessors return *just* the named components, while the `to_` methods return the composite whole value floored to the target unit. Finally the `to_Part` methods on `Duration` emulate the behaviour of the `get_` methods if `Duration` were imagined to be composed of one instance of each `ChronoUnit` value. The odd one out in this virtual component access is `toDaysPart`. I suspect the reason for this is that while HOURS, MINUTES, SECONDS, MILLIS, MICROS and NANOS could be considered discrete and non-overlapping in terms of the components they reference, when considering DAYS as a component value it is not clear if we mean day of the week, day of the month or day of the year - all three are common conventions. Similarly MONTHS and YEARS each have variable length. So it appears the author chose to be unambiguous and consider DAYS to represent the coarsest component in that hierarchy. Personally I think its all a bit of a dog's breakfast and wondered why those two methods were identical for a while myself before reaching this conclusion.